# Access iCloud Drive in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, icloud

I am using Jupyter Notebooks (through Anaconda) on a Mac OS X Sierra. Now I would like to access a notebook saved in my iCloud Drive. However, I have been unable to find a way to access iCloud via the Juypter interface. I can of course upload a file with the "Upload" button, but not access the file sitting in my iCloud directly, which I would much prefer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having found the solution to my question here is what to do:

Click on spotlight, type `terminal` to open a terminal window.

Enter the startup folder by typing `cd /Users/username/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/foldername`.

Type `jupyter notebook` to launch the Jupyter Notebook App and it will display your iCloud Drive folder.

More here: http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html

Answer (score 18):

While someone can launch the Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook software from the iCloud directory, as described in the accepted response, this will need to be done each and every time you want to access Jupyter notebooks within iCloud. Instead I prefer to create a symbolic link (symlink...a shortcut) to my iCloud folder, in my home directory. This will always be present. In doing this I can launch Jupyter Lab or a Jupyter Notebook from any folder or from Anaconda Navigator and I will always see a "folder" to iCloud.

To do this you need to open a Terminal and copy and paste the statement below into the Terminal window and hit `return`:

`ln -s ~/Library/Mobile*Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/ iCloud`

After creating this symlink, there will always be an `iCloud` folder that you can browse in your home directory. You can use whatever name you want by replacing the "iCloud" at the on the statement above with your own name.

Comment: This is awesome and should be the default answer to this question. Saved me a ton of time. Thanks!

Comment: Loved this solution. Easy and intuitive

Answer (score 4):

### Mac: Access your iCloud Documents folder with Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab

Hi!
In my case what I do it's:

1. Open a `Terminal` in Your Mac
2. Type:

   > `cd ~/Library/Mobile*Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents`
3. Verify you are at the right folder. Type

   > `pwd`
4. Open Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab. Type:

   > `jupyter notebook`

or type:

> `jupyter lab`

5. Your browser will open a Jupyter Notebook (/Lab) and you'll see your iCloud `Documents` Folder and all the subfolders included on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PyiCloud](https://github.com/picklepete/pyicloud)

You can query some basic information like your device info, contacts, calendar info - but as of this writing, it has issues getting data from Files Storage.

PyiCloud documentation on their github is well done, it just has some limitations.

Answer (score 0):

For more some great & insightful background information about how to untangle the confusing mess that Apple has made for us to interact with iCloud - and which will help when trying to find Jupyter notebooks - take a look at [this](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/05/03/going-for-icloud-drive-or-the-whole-way-with-desktop-documents-folders/) and [this](https://www.4macsolutions.com/2017/09/27/understanding-desktop-and-documents-folder-syncing/). In particular, there are two aspects to this confusion:

1. If you have enabled syncing with your Desktop and Documents folders,
   OS X will manage where the files exist, either in both iCloud and on
   your local machine or solely in iCloud.
2. The way that iCloud is implemented depends on what version of OS X you are on.